# The meaning of "for it to be"

Tags: expressions

*"Work is becoming too important for it to be of dubious quality."*

What is the meaning of this sentence, and especially *for it to be*?

Answer (score 2):

The relevant construction is *X is too Y for Z*, where *Z* is expressing some standard of comparison, or limit, in respect of which *X* is too *Y*. Examples:

> These shoes are too big for me.
>
> The print is too small for me to read.
>
> That song is too jolly for a funeral.
>
> That hole is too small for him to get through.

So the meaning is that for less important work, the quality would not matter, but this particular piece of work is so important that it must be of good quality.

**Edit:** GEdgar pointed out that I was making an unwarranted assumption that this was about written work, so I have removed that.

Comment: +1 for explanation.  But: How did you find out that the quote refers to *writing*?

Comment: You're right: that is an assumption I made which may not be correct. It could refer to manufacturing, or other things